# deploying django site (wsgi)

Tags: django, deployment, mod-wsgi

Trying to use 2 different settings file for production and dev.

I set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='mysite.settings_production'
Works perfectly when running server with `runserver`

When I run it with apache though, apache doesn't seem to use the setting in the `~/.bash_profile` and instead use `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")` in the wsgi.py file

I guess it's maybe because apache is running on different user , not mine.. 
ok.. so it seems it's running as www-data on my ec2 ubuntu.

So I have to create the /home/www-data/.bash_profile and set the env variable?

It seems like so much hassle to use a different settings file.
Is there an obviously easier way to do this? 
(I don't want to change the wsgi.py file, because it's source controlled)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash_profile is completely the wrong way to do this.

The correct way is to use the wsgi.py file. However, since you don't want to do this (although I don't understand what it being version-controlled has to do with anything) then you can set environment variables directly in your Apache configuration using SetEnv:

```
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
```

Comment: I can do this in httpd.conf?   (I want to use settings.py in my dev computer and settings_production.py in production computer. Since wsgi.py is version controlled by git or svn, it will affect both deployments)

Comment: mod_wsgi docs specifically mention that SetEnv has no effect on the system environment for the called script

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's really wrong way. Common method to have separate settings for different environment is to store environment-dependent in local_settings.py (or whatever you name it) and imprort from settings.py

```
from local_settings.py import *
```

don't put local_settings.py under project repository as you will override it with each commit. If you want to keep a sample of local settings, put into a separate file, e.g. local_settings.py.example

You can import local settings at the beginning of settings.py (so settings.py settings would override local settings), or at the end, or have two local settings files for both cases.